# How to use COUNT() and GROUP BY to display number of employees in each department

Tags: mysql, sql, group-by, count

Please consider the two tables - Employee and Department

```
Employee:
EmployeeID
Name
DeptID

Department:
DepartmentID
DeptName
LocID

Employee.DeptID is a foreign key to Department.DepartmentID
```

How would one display a list of all departments (Department Names) and the number of employees in each department? The output should look like this:

```
DepartmentName         Number of employees
Accounts               30
HR                     24
Production             400
Sales/Marketing        250

etc...
```

Comment: Your title says it all. Use `COUNT(*)` and `GROUP BY DepartmentID`

Comment: Join with the `Department` table to get the department name.

Comment: Kinda seems like it is

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use `GROUP BY`

```
 SELECT d.deptID, count(e.deptID)
 FROM Department d
 LEFT JOIN Employee e ON d.DeptID = e.DeptID
 GROUP BY d.deptId
```

and `LEFT JOIN` is used to include departments that do not have employees.

Answer (score 1):

> SELECT DeptName AS DepartmentName, COUNT(EmployeeID) AS NumberOfEmployees FROM Employee INNER JOIN Department ON DeptID = DepartmentID GROUP BY DepartmentID